# Why do JavaScript frameworks save core methods for quick reference?

Tags: javascript, performance

[jQuery Example](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/01-core.html#section-23)

[underscore.js Example](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-7)

How does that work? How does it make your program faster?

Say I declared
`var push = ArrayProto.push;`

Would the functionality still be the same?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.push(4);
//[1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Comment: It's easing the access to those functions. Not necessarily making the code run faster but making it quicker to type.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about speed or performance.  Frameworks rarely are.  It's about expressiveness of the code you're writing.

When you're using a framework, the idea is generally to write code "the framework's way".  To organize and express logic in a way that is consistent and canonical with the style of that framework.  This makes it easier to read and understand the code, which in turn makes it easier to share with teams.

In all likelihood, the builders of these frameworks found that they were using these core functions often and that with a simple shortcut to those functions they could streamline the code they were writing a little bit and make the resulting use of the framework more clear for users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it doesn't really make any difference in performance, as the variable still references the same function, but it does make a difference in minification.

For instance this

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(array, [value1, value2])
```

could be minified to

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [v,k])
```

so the function and the properties can't really be minified.

If the code uses `Array.prototype.push` multiple places, like jQuery and Underscore does, using a variable

```
var push = Array.prototype.push;
```

Means that anywhere in the code, something like this

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(array, [value1, value2])
```

can be minified to just

```
p.apply(a,[v,k])
```

which saves a few bytes.

You'll see the same thing with other common variables, for instance

```
var document  = window.document;
```

means the library can minify `window.document` to just `d`, saving 14 bytes everytime `document` is used in the code.

Comment: Wow! Really interesting and clever trick to save memory! Is this a commonly used technique?

Comment: @Ryan it doesn't save memory. It will enable both the programmer to write less (using `push` instead of `Array.prototype.push` every time) and if the library is minified, it will have less size, so it'd be faster to download. This has little impact on performance.